# Auto switch between network adapters

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, automation

So, i'm looking for a method or windows program that essentially does like what "adaptive wifi" does om android, but for windows 7.

So the idea is that while connected through cable (LAN) and the modem or isp have issues, i want a method of making it auto switch to the wireless adapter which is connected to the my mobile phone hotspot with a 4g connection.

The network proiority (metric) function in windows only works when the connection is fully dead, i.e. cable is disconnected or router got shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

1. Open the "Network and Sharing Center" interface, you can right-click the taskbar network icon, from the pop-up right-click menu to select the "Open Network Sharing Center" item.
2. From the open "Network and Sharing Center" window, click the "Change the adapter settings" button to enter the detailed settings interface for network connections.
3. Click on the "Advanced" menu item in the menu bar and select the "Advanced Settings" item from the open drop-down menu to enter. As shown in the figure:
4. At this time, the "Advanced Settings" interface will be opened, switch to the "Adapter and Binding" tab, select the "Wireless Connection" or "Wired Connection" item in the "Connection" list, and click the "Move Up" or "Move Down" button to adjust the priority of network connection.

[image]

5. Usually, the connection above the Connection list is preferred. As shown in the figure, when the Local Connection (i.e. wired Connection) is available, the wired connection is used first. When a wired connection is not available and a wireless connection is available, it is automatically transferred to a wired connection to access the network.
6. At the same time, the computer can also set the order of accessing information on the network, so as to achieve more efficient network access function. Switch to the Order of Providers tab, where you can set the order in which the program accesses the network.

Comment: Like i already said in my original post. This wont work until the connection is totally dead (0 packets of anything). In that time, a network-critical service will disconnect because of long loss of network activity.

Comment: That tab is missing from my Windows 10 Home 21H2 19044.2006 Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0, but maybe `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings` network discovery, auto setup, and auto-connect to WiFi helps.