# Fall back to secondary connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

My connection to my ISP is unstable. I can connect to my phone's hotspot using wifi. Is it possible to have both connections active but if my ethernet connection goes down make internet automatically work through wifi?

I've checked [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1393630/auto-switch-between-network-adapters) question but Adapter and Bindinds tab doesn't seem to be exist in Windows 10.

Comment: Is your computer connected to the modem of the ISP via WiFi?

Comment: @harrymc: no I'm connected through ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer has two network adapters : Ethernet and WiFi, the first
is connected to the ISP's modem and the second via the phone
(which is a different supplier).

If both the Ethernet and WiFi modems are connected, Windows should
prefer the Ethernet connection, but fall-back automatically to
WiFi if it fails.

You may combine the two networks into one, for faster and more
reliable internet connection.
Unfortunately, the software that does it, by
[Speedify](https://speedify.com/),
is commercial.